# getting error :Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json, database

Stuck and need help. JSON parser cannot convert data so I can use the username and password to login.

```
jsonParser = new JSONParser();
public JSONObject loginUser(String username, String password) {
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    return json;
}
```

PHP part of the code:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($json);
```

Comment: What do you think the error means?

Comment: `$json[] = $r;` indicates an array. `JSONObject json` is an object.

Comment: Where does `loginURL` comes from? What is in that variable?

Comment: the url to the database @speedy1034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the comments of the @njzk2 the solution should be to change your PHP coding:

But then you just get the first:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json = $r;
    break;
}
print json_encode($json);
```

Or change your Java Coding to a JsonArray

```
jsonParser = new JSONParser();
public JSONArray loginUser(String username, String password) {
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    // change the following line, to the correct method. Which parser do you use?
    JSONArray json = jsonParser.getJSONArrayFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    return json;
}
```